# Remove %20 to nothing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET site I have a redirect that will load a new url.

The original url is....

```
site.com/7201231234/First%20Last/campaign/7201231234/
```

On redirect I get (campaign%20 is the issue now)

```
site.com/7201231234/First%20Last/campaign%20/7201231234/`
```

I have some javascript that redirects the string based on selection. I use a + to create the new string. Is there anyway to eliminate `%20` to make it campaign/7201231234?

The JS Used is as follows

```
<script>
    //Change the Campaign
         $("#CampaignID").change(function () {
             window.location = 
    "http://localhost:53049/@ViewBag.Phone/@ViewBag.AgentName/" + $("#CampaignID option:selected").text() + "/@ViewBag.DNIS";
        });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the code that generates the url?

Comment: I assume your `campaign` is some string you set before you do redirect. What is you trim this string before you set it?

Comment: `%20` is a space. You probably have a space at the end of the string you're building in JS. Trim that out and you're all set.

Comment: [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) will decode `'%20'` and other encoded characters (meaning `%20` will be replaced with `' '`), otherwise there's always [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: added js to post

Answer (score 2):

`$("#CampaignID option:selected").text()` probably has a trailing space. Try `$("#CampaignID option:selected").text().trim()`.